# Non-empty collection error in ManifoldLearning.jl

Tags: julia

I'm trying to use the `Isomap` algorithm from the `ManifoldLearning.jl` package (https://github.com/wildart/ManifoldLearning.jl). However, following the usage example provided in the docs (http://manifoldlearningjl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/isomap.html), throws the below error:

`ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: collection must be non-empty
 in extrema at reduce.jl:337
 in classical_mds at /Users/rprechelt/.julia/v0.4/MultivariateStats/src/cmds.jl:75
 in transform at /Users/rprechelt/.julia/v0.4/ManifoldLearning/src/isomap.jl:75
 in isomap at /Users/rprechelt/code/julia/subwoofer.jl:198`

where line 198 is `transform(Isomap, X; k=12, d=2)` where `X` is a non-empty (verified using `isempty`) array where each column is a data sample.

I've tried to trace the error back from `reduce.jl` but I can't seem to locate where collection is becoming non-empty. The same array (`X`) works perfectly with LTSA, and other algorithms from the `ManifoldLearning.jl` package, just not Isomap.

Has anyone encountered this before? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that sometimes happens is that if your points are, for example, exactly on a line, then a matrix created by MDS is rank 1, and depending on the implementation, this may cause errors if you are searching for an Isomap embedding of more than 1 direction.

Dirty hack fix: add a small amount of random noise to all your input points (i think to all the elements of your array X).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion; it turns out that the particular dataset that was causing Isomap to fail contained three distinct orthogonal lines in the dataset; I ended up transitioning to LTSA for a number of reasons (one of which was this behaviour in Isomap). That being said, I tried the noise and it worked fairly well; thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Isomap invokes classical multidimensional scaling on geodesic distance matrix constructed from an original data. Commonly, MDS algorithm performs an spectral decomposition to find a proper embedding. From the above error, it looks that the decomposition returns an empty spectrum of a geodesic distance matrix. In any case, it is better to open an error issue with the package project on GitHub for a further investigation.